# Updating dictionary in elastic search

Tags: python, dictionary, elasticsearch

I have a document in ElasticSearch which contains a dictionary. Initially it is empty but later on I update it using _update API and insert few key/value pairs. Now I need to empty the dictionary again. I tried using _update API and passed empty dictionary to it ({}) but old key/value pairs are still there. I cannot use ctx scripts. One solution is to pass null and then reinsert updated dictionary but that will cause two ES calls. _update API states that it merges dictionary but no option to empty it out.

Answer (score 0):

So, to recap, you have indexed a document in your Elasticsearch like this

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/123 -d '{"field1":"value1"}'
```

Then you inserted a couple more fields using the `_update` endpoint:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/123/_update -d '{
    "doc": {"field2": "value2"}
}'
```

Now your document `123` looks like this and you would like to empty it to contain new data.

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
}
```

You can simply re-index a new document with the new fields but the same id, like we did with the first command above:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/123 -d '{"field3":"value3"}'
```

And the document `123` now looks like

```
{
    "field3": "value3"
}
```

However, if you need to empty the document first and update it at a later point in time, you can simply delete it

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/123
```

Since the document will be missing, your app can consider that it is empty (semantically speaking).

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I needed to delete a dictionary inside the document. {
    "field1": "value1",
    "dictionary": {"field2", "value2"}
}. I need to set "dictionary" to empty.

Comment: You could set the `dictionary` field to `null` with `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/123/_update -d '{
    "doc": {"dictionary": null}
}'`